# How to know with jQuery the last changed select element among two?

Tags: jquery

There are two `select` elements. Their default value is "" showing the text "Select a value". I want to know with `jQuery` which of them the user selected last in the case their values are both not "" ?

Comment: using the `bind` function but it seems difficult :)

Comment: I'm afraid jQuery doesn't track this kind of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track this manually:

```
<select id="s1" class="watched">
   ...
</select>
<select id="s2" class="watched">
   ...
</select>
```

...

```
var lastChanged = $();
$('select.watched').on('change'){
  lastChanged = $(this);
}
```

Note that it's not neccessary to set the class as long as you can identify the `select`s through other means (e.g. `$('form#my-form select')` or even `$('select')` if there are no other `select`s on the page).